# Fastest way to do this double summation?

Tags: r

What is the fastest way to do this summation[image] in R?

This is what I have so far

```
ans = 0
for (i in 1:dimx[1]){
  for (j in 1:dimx[2]){
    ans = ans + ((x[i,j] - parameters$mu)^2)/(parameters$omega_2[i]*parameters$sigma_2[j])
  }
}
```

where `omega_2`, and `sigma_2` are omega^2 and sigma^2 respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing fancy:

```
# sample data
m <- matrix(1:20, 4)
sigma <- 1:ncol(m)
omega <- 1:nrow(m)
mu <- 2

sum(((m - mu) / outer(omega, sigma))^2)
```

Comment: As a side note, if the denominator had been $\omega_i + \sigma_j$ (an addition rather than a multiplication), then this solution still can be used with `outer(omega, sigma, \`+\`)`. This solution is therefore more general than the one that follow.

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is quite easy to vectorize this kind of operations. In this case, though, it is a bit trickier when `n` is not equal to `m` and also because of double summation. But here is how we can proceed:

```
# n = 3, m = 2
xs <- cbind(1:3, 4:6)
omegas <- 1:3
sigmas <- 1:2
mu <- 3

sum((t((xs - mu) / omegas) / sigmas)^2)
# [1] 5
```

Here we use recycling three times and `t()` to divide appropriate elements by `sigmas`.