# Multiple summations over indices in R

Tags: r, sum

I would have put some sample data but I do not know the first thing on how to interprete the image below in R.

[image]

I've looked at

[Fastest way to do this double summation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918051/fastest-way-to-do-this-double-summation)

but could not extrapolate the answer there to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aperm` and exploit the vectorization. You must indicate which are the "common" dimensions (i.e. the dimensions contained in both `X` and `C`), permute `X` and multiply. Something like:

```
#declare which are the dimensions in X common to C
commonDims<-c(3,4)
#the other dimensions are the "uncommon" ones
uncommonDims<-setdiff(seq_along(dims),commonDims)
#then you can get the sum
sum(as.vector(aperm(X,c(commonDims,uncommonDims)))*as.vector(C))
```

We test the result above with the one obtained with `for` loops:

```
set.seed(456)
dims<-c(5,6,2,3,8)
commonDims<-c(3,4)
uncommonDims<-setdiff(seq_along(dims),commonDims)
C<-array(runif(prod(dims[commonDims])),dims[commonDims])
X<-array(runif(prod(dims)),dims)
sum(as.vector(aperm(X,c(commonDims,uncommonDims)))*as.vector(C))
#[1] 371.3749
#Calculation through loops
rsum<-0
for (i in 1:dims[1]) 
  for (j in 1:dims[2]) 
   for (k in 1:dims[3]) 
    for (r in 1:dims[4]) 
     for (t in 1:dims[5]) rsum<-rsum + X[i,j,k,r,t]*C[k,r]
rsum
#[1] 371.3749
```